iOS15.5のアプリを新しいOSで実機検証したい
Sonomaの環境下でiOS15.5のアプリを実機検証したいのですが、いくら方法を探っても解答は見つかりませんでした。Simulatorには既に15.5のOSは入れています。
Xcode 15.0.1
iPhoneSE (第2世代)
iOS 17.5.1
